# Type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-props

I have a component that looks like this. This version works perfectly:

```
export default function StatusMessage(isAdded: boolean, errorMessage: string) {
  if (isAdded) {
    return <ResultAlert severity="success" text="User Added" />;
  } else {
    if (errorMessage !== '') {
      if (
        errorMessage.includes('email')
      ) {
        return <ResultAlert severity="error" />;
      }
      if (
        errorMessage.includes('phone number')
      ) {
        return (
          <ResultAlert severity="error" text="" />
        );
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I am trying to change the way I export it. I am trying this:

```
type StatusMessageProps = {
  isAdded: boolean; 
  errorMessage: string;
}

export const StatusMessage: React.FunctionComponent<StatusMessageProps> = ({
  isAdded,
  errorMessage
}) => {
```

but i keep getting an error that:

```
Type '({ isAdded, errorMessage }: PropsWithChildren<StatusMessageProps>) => Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<StatusMessageProps>'.
  Type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null'.
```

```
I am using the same method on different pages but the error is only here
```

Edit:

I am using this component like this:

```
 const [isAdded, setIsAdded] = useState(false);

{isSubmitted && StatusMessage(isAdded, errorMessage)}
```

it gives me an error on isAdded that

```
Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PropsWithChildren<StatusMessageProps>'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You must have forgotten return a value in your component. Are you forgetting return null since void 0 is unacceptable result of a React component?

```js
export const StatusMessage: React.FunctionComponent<StatusMessageProps> = ({
  isAdded,
  errorMessage
}) => {
  if (isAdded) {
    return <ResultAlert severity="success" text="User Added" />;
  } else {
    if (errorMessage !== '') {
      if (
        errorMessage.includes('email')
      ) {
        return <ResultAlert severity="error" />;
      }
      if (
        errorMessage.includes('phone number')
      ) {
        return (
          <ResultAlert severity="error" text="" />
        );
      } 
    }

    // Here where you missed
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you do as you tried to invoke your component `StatusMessage(isAdded, errorMessage)`?

Comment: calling a graphql query and setting values accordingly. added in the qs

Comment: it seems like you have a same name `StatusMessage` for both a function & a component. Can you check that then?

Comment: calling it like this worked ```<StatusMessage isAdded={isAdded} errorMessage={errorMessage}/>```

Answer (score 16):

In my case I had an auth wrapper component where a loading page component would be returned if the auth was loading or the user was unauthenticated otherwise the children props would be returned.

The issue was that I needed to wrap the children in empty html tags.

```
return <>{children}</>;
```

Comment: What about this rule then? https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-useless-fragment.md

Answer (score 5):

in my case `return null;` didn't work so I `return <></>;`